# How to get a item's coordinates while it is animating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

I can animate something across the screen like so:

```
aView.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,50,50); 
[UIView animateWithDuration:25.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:
     ^{ 
         aView.frame = CGRectMake(200,100,50,50);         
     } 
         completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         aView.hidden = YES; 
     }
 ];
```

..but how do I get the position of the item while it is animating? If I put a button on the screen and use this action

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"x pos:%f", aframe.origin.x)l
}
```

then all I get from this is

```
x pos:200.00
```

..which is the **final** position of the item, but not the current. How do I get the current?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `CALayer`'s [`presentationLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer) property. It holds the current values of the layer being animated.

You will have to import *QuartzCore* framework.

**EDIT**

Specifically:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
// ...
CGPoint inMotionPosition = myView.layer.presentationLayer.position;
```