# iphone development: how to create an animation by using NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, nstimer

In my app I have this code in viewWillAppear. It simply animates random object from top of the screen to the bottom. The problem is I need to detect collision and what I have learnt so far is it is impossible to retrieve the coordinates at any time for an animation. so how can I implement it by using NSTimer? or shall I use NSTimer? I could not figure it out. Any clue will be appreciated.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        p = arc4random_uniform(320)%4+1;

        CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake(p*50, -50, 50, 50);
        CGRect endFrame   = CGRectMake(p*50, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) + 50,
                                       50,
                                       50);

        animatedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:startFrame];
        animatedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self.view addSubview:animatedView];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f
                              delay:i * 0.5f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             animatedView.frame = endFrame;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [animatedView removeFromSuperview];
                         }];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement:

> is it is impossible to retrieve the coordinates at any time for an
>   animation

seems incorrect did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022327/how-to-get-a-items-coordinates-while-it-is-animating)?

It looks like you can use the CALayer's `presentationLayer` property to extract coordinates info during an animation:

```
CGRect movingFrame = [[yourView.layer presentationLayer] frame];
```

I will use this info to check time to time if there is a collision during the animation. So I will use the timer to check the collision status not for animating the views.

Answer (score 3):

I would ditch `NSTimer` for `CADisplayLink` to send a message to your target. `NSTimer` can cause stuttering animations since it doesn't synchronize with the device's screen refresh rate. `CADisplayLink` does exactly that and makes your animations run like butter.

Documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Ultimately, using `CADisplayLink` looks something like this:

```
- (id) init {
    // ...
    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update:)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    // ...
}

- (void) update {
    [myView updatePositionOrSomethingElse];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have your objects animate in small increments (in a loop may be). Every time you complete your animation, you can get the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the beginAnimations - commitAnimations syntax in a for cycle it could count for eg. till 10, so after each cycle you can check for collision

```
CGRect incrementedViewFrame;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{

      incrementedViewFrame = CGRectMake(/*calculate the coords here*/);

      if(collision)
      {
           //do stuff
      }
      else
      {
           //do an other animation cycle
          [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
          [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1f];
          [[self viewToAnimate]setFrame:incrementedViewFrame];
          [UIView commitAnimations];
      }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer but I really do not understand. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: sure, but tell me than which two objects' collision you're trying to detect