# iphone development: collision detection does not work for the animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, imageview, collision-detection

The code below simply creates small squares from top of the screen and moves to the bottom. I also have an UIImageView(player) which is controlled by the accelerometer on the x axis. The aim is not touching the animated object. like a simple race game. Although I have no error I cant detect the collision. I could not find the mistake in my code. What can be the problem?

```
-(void)printOut:(NSTimer*)timer1;
{


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        p = arc4random_uniform(320)%4+1;

        CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake(p*50, -50, 50, 50);
        CGRect endFrame   = CGRectMake(p*50, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) + 50,
                                       50,
                                       50);

        animatedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:startFrame];
        animatedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self.view addSubview:animatedView];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f
                              delay:i * 0.5f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                         animations:^{animatedView.frame = endFrame;}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {[animatedView removeFromSuperview];}];


        CGRect movingFrame = [[animatedView.layer presentationLayer] frame];

        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, movingFrame)){
            [timer invalidate];
            NSLog(@"asdad");

            UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lost" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You were hit!"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }

    }

    [timer1 invalidate];

}
```

Comment: I know you are looking for a specific answer (and I guess you will soon have one). However I do suggest you to use already

Comment: @Silli sorry I could not understand what you meant?

Comment: Sorry I didn't think I posted it :) anyway I wanted to suggest you to use already existing framework for 2d games development such as cocos2d. www.cocos2d-iphone.org/ it is provided with physics engines (i.e. box2D or chipmunk physics) in which collision detection (for any kind of 2d shape) is already implemented and tested!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect the collision because the only frame values the system is ever aware of for your animation are the beginning frame, and the end frame. So unless the object you are trying to detect collision of collides with the beginning or end frame of the first object, you need to find a different way to detect it. `UIView` animations were designed for aesthetics not game logic.

Comment: I was also thinking like that but then I learnt it is wrong.

check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12141217/1587184